# iFrame in Hybrid Application

Tags: html, hybrid-mobile-app

Now I have a requirement to convert the different web pages into a hybrid application. The developer have to spend a lots of time to do the task as it is in different type of styles and standards. To overcome this productivity issue I planned to use iFrame so that we no need to change anything in the HTML pages.

Now the question is, if I use iFrame in hybrid application then is it cause anything or any performances issues occur.

I Googled about this iframe things but many of them are not suggesting to use iframe on web but I am not sure about the Hybrid application.

Thanks in advance!

-Murali Krishnan

Comment: any response friends?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would  want to use an iframe. Within a hybrid app you can load the webpage of you already have as a webview. Hence that is already the web page loaded. Please correct me if I have misunderstood you.

Consider your page is located at `http://example.com`. You can load the hybrid app's webview with the webview pointing to `http://example.com`. Therefore, you already have your webpage loaded within the app and there would not be a necessity of iframe.

Using the hybrid app approach you would also be able to use the native features available with the mobile device to improve the functionality of your webpage.

In the performance point of view,  using iframe within the webview (though never necessary) of the hybrid app will definitely reduce the performance of the app.

Comment: If you want to have the JS to Objective-C communication then you would have to use iFrames without refreshing your page on the UIWebView?